# How do I preserve file permissions in a custom external project added to Android AOSP?

Tags: android, android-source

I've downloaded (using repo) the Android 4.0 OS source code (from here - http://source.android.com/). I'm trying to add a new external project (in external/ for example external/libhelloworld) to the build system so that it is built into the system image. In that project I would like to deploy a shell script and have it keep it's permissions which are rwxr-xr-x but when I build it and load the emulator I see the file permissions have been changed to rw-r--r--. I am deploying the script to /etc. My Android.mk file looks like this

LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
 LOCAL_MODULE := libhelloworld
 LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
 LOCAL_MODULE_SRC := helloworld.c
 include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
 LOCAL_MODULE := myscript.sh
 LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
 LOCAL_MODULE_SRC := $(LOCAL_MODULE)
 LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := EXECUTABLES
 LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT)/etc/helloscripts
 include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)

I see the script permissions are preserved when it is copied into the intermediates area but then the permissions are changed at some point after that in the build process. Any idea why the script permissions are not being preserved when it gets added into the system image?  Is there something I'm missing from my Android.mk?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

System image filesytem modifications you can change in this file:

```
system/core/include/private/android_filesystem_config.h
```

Try to change permissions there. If you have problems, please, post here.

Comment: That sounds like the missing link I am after! I can't check it solves my problem for two days but when I can confirm it fixes my issue I'll accept this as the answer. The AOSP build environment has been very intuitive until hitting this issue and it seems like a shame to have to change a header file to preserve permissions, I was hoping there would be something in the build environment to do that.

Comment: This header is used in the native code of Android. I think if you continue develop for the platform you'll find where it can be used! Good luck!