# How I can set file permissions in a custom project added to Android AOSP

Tags: android, permissions, android-source

I add to AOSP device-owner APP.

1. Create directory at packages/apps/myapp
2. Copy myapp.apk , device-owner.xml to packages/apps/myapp
3. Create Android.mk:

> ```
> LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
> include $(CLEAR_VARS)
> $(shell mkdir -p $(TARGET_OUT_DATA)/system)
> $(shell cp $(LOCAL_PATH)/device_owner.xml $(TARGET_OUT_DATA)/system)
> LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
> LOCAL_MODULE := myapp
> LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := PRESIGNED
> LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true
> LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=  $(LOCAL_MODULE).apk
> LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := APPS
> LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := $(COMMON_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SUFFIX)
> LOCAL_POST_INSTALL_CMD := chown system:system $(TARGET_OUT_DATA)/system/device_owner.xml
> include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
> ```

4. device-owner.xml

> ```
> <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
> <device-owner package="com.test.test.myapp" />
> ```

5. After flash userdata.img to device I will have permissions:

> -rw-r--r-- root     root          112 2016-09-22 06:29 device_owner.xml

but must have such as after dpm set-device-owner com.test.test.myapp/.DeviceAdminReceiver

> -rw------- system     system          112 2016-09-22 06:29
>   device_owner.xml

How can I set permissions for /data/system/device-owner.xml via Android.xml or another way?

Comment: Seems to be duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10878369/how-do-i-preserve-file-permissions-in-a-custom-external-project-added-to-android

Answer (score 4):

Thanks, I found another solution. 
Edit "system/core/rootdir/init.rc".
Add permissions to section "on post-fs-data".

```
chown system system /data/system/device_owner.xml
chmod 0600 /data/system/device_owner.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if I was unclear - I mean that you can modify permission of your file in `system/core/include/private/android_filesystem_config.h` as described here: http://paldan.altervista.org/dir-and-files-permissions-in-the-aosp-filesystem/?doing_wp_cron=1474724093.3321709632873535156250 or place device-owner.xml to a folder with proper permissions