# Set file permissions in Android source code

Tags: android, linux-kernel, android-source, chmod

In my Android 10 image I have the file (of type character) `/dev/i2c-1`:

> crw ------- 1 root root 89, 1 2021-05-26 11:51 /dev/i2c-1

I have the source code for this Android and I would like this file to have read and write permission for any user, that is, it would be as follows:

> crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 89, 1 2021-05-26 11:51 /dev/i2c-1

Otherwise, I have to run the `chmod` command every time the device is restarted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the access permissions in two places:

1. where your create the file
2. in init rc files. See [examples](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:device/google/crosshatch/init.hardware.diag.rc.user;drc=a8954a729a6da85ff4c3268e6dfa3f230d2ff25c;l=18)

```
on init
   chmod 666 /dev/i2c-1
```

Comment: I did it according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39639703/how-i-can-set-file-permissions-in-a-custom-project-added-to-android-aosp.
But I put the commands in "on boot" instead of "on post-fs-data", because I saw that "on boot" is one of the last labels.